# Flutter TexField and TextFormField duplicates text when using initial value or controller to set initial text

Tags: android, flutter

Within a flutter application that has TextField or TextFormField the text can get duplicated upon first time data entry.

When first entering a keypress, within a field that already has text pre-filled, the text duplicates then your keypress is attached.

I am experiencing something that exhibits this behavior on my Samsung Galaxy S7, S8 and S9 (only devices I have to test with). This doesn't occur within the emulator (Galaxy Nexus9 and Pixel 2).

If I place a space at the end of the field, this problem doesn't happen, however, if I tap in middle of a pre filled field (using controller or initialValue) and press a key it does occur.

Here is a barebones source example:

```
class SampleTextFormPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _SampleTextFormPage();
}

class _SampleTextFormPage extends State<SampleTextFormPage> {
    final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    TextEditingController _txtController;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        _txtController = TextEditingController(text:'Using Controller');
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) { Scaffold scaffold = new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Text Entry',
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white)
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo
        ),
        body:  Column(children: [
            //field 1
            TextField(
                 autocorrect: false,
                 autofocus: true,
                 controller: _txtController,
            ),

           //field 2
           TextFormField(
               autocorrect: false,
               autofocus: true,
               initialValue: 'Using initialValue',
           )
        ])
    );

    return scaffold;
    }
}
```

Note: I am on the latest release of flutter and I have reverted to multiple versions of Flutter (all the way to the first release that supports Dart 2) and this problem still exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution?, I got the same problem

Comment: Chime in here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31512

Comment: MrQwerty, sorry for the late response.  Using Flutter 1.5 has helped improve some of the issue however not completely.  For typical words it seems to be fine, however,  entering in a website address will cause the same issue when reaching the top domain (e.g. .com). I tested this on an S9 and S9 Note.

Answer (score 5):

As @[DarkNeuron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536485/darkneuron) mentioned, it is a known Flutter issue on Samsung devices. There's no complete cure for it for now.

As of February 2020 it was determined the issue is connected with Samsung keyboard caching process and autocorrect. In the Flutter github possible temporary workaround proposed: use `keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword` for all you text inputs. But there is a report it is not valid for at least Korean language. One another suggestion is to check for Samsung device and build accordingly:

```
keyboardType: samsungKeyboard ? TextInputType.visiblePassword : TextInputType.emailAddress,
autoFocus: false,
```

The part of the problem (duplicates on punctuation) fixed two weeks ago. But the main part of the problem is still observed.

More details you can find here: [Flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31512#issuecomment-580425520).

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and fixed it with this simple temporary solution: just add to initialValue's end a space. Example:

```
initialValue: controller.text + ' ',
```